# Literary/poetic way of saying hello

Tags: single-word-requests

I have heard farewell as an old-fashioned or formal form of goodbye. But what can I say instead of hello? As far as I know, the word, greetings, can be used instead of hello, but I am not sure it is a good choice or not. For example how John Milton says hello in his literary works?

Comment: Have you tried using a thesaurus?

Comment: Thesaurus cannot prove it is literary or poetic.

Comment: True, but it will help you find other choices, and you can decide which are poetic enough for you.

Comment: The only choice is greetings.

Comment: "poetic" and "literary" are style choices, not something that can be proved objectively.

Comment: I'm partial to "ahoy", but it might not be the register you want.

Comment: Good day?......

Comment: @user888379: Good call. I'm pretty sure Milton uses it in Comus.

Comment: I don't know about Milton, but if you are asking about the language of his time, "Good day to you, sir/madam/[name]" would do.

Comment: Your main question is interesting and suitable for the site, raising issues of synonymity & register. On new inspection, the two who voted to close the question did so because they thought it a matter of opinion. I believe they were erroneous votes, there being very few alternatives for Hello to choose from, and your question making clear that you wanted the poetic or literary ones. But if you pose questions such as the Milton question you run the risk of  closure for "lack of research": I only refer to the site rules, which encourage folk to give their own research before posing a question.

Comment: Good morning/afternoon/evening Not literary, perhaps, but certainly used.

Comment: @Mari-LouA May not work if you say it to your friend living in a different country :-)

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities are:

The Latin greeting **Ave**

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ave)
> *ave*
> an expression of greeting or of leave-taking : HAIL,

Or the slightly archaic **Hail**

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hail)
> *hail*
> archaic —used as a salutation

The two are discussed together in:

> [Oxford Reference](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095436865)
> *Ave*:
> Latin greeting, meaning ‘hail, be well’. According to Suetonius' Lives of the Caesars, gladiators in the arena saluted the Roman emperor with the words, ‘Ave Caesar, morituri te salutant [Hail Caesar, those who are about to die salute you].’